# Set the last modified time of a directory in Windows

Tags: ruby, file-io

Is it possible to set the last modified time of a directory in Windows 7 from Ruby?

I tried this:

```
FileUtils.touch directory_name, :mtime => new_last_modified_time
```

This works fine with files, but when I apply it to a directory, I get an exception.

```
C:/Progra~2/PUPPET~1/PUPPET~1/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1137:in `utime': Permission denied - C:/temp/ruby-unzip-target/smc/ (Errno::EACCES)
```

This even happens if I run as administrator.

Update: 
I tried this from an administrator console and get the same error:

```
File.utime(Time.new, last_modified, target_file)
```

I created the directory and can delete it via Windows explorer.

Comment: I just saw the error.. You don't have permission to change the mtime of the directory. That's the problem. Do you have access to change the directory content by hand ?

Comment: You first need to change the owner of the dir to you using ::chown. Then I hope you can do..

Comment: In using chown, how do I get the user number and group number of the current user? I do not see any worked examples of chown that do this.